# How do you delete records from a database via LSXODBC

Tags: lotus-notes, lotusscript

I've got an agent running which pushes data from a Notes db to a Postgres db.  I now need to build a function that deletes records from a table or does a truncate.  The doc isn't that great so I'm finding it a bit hard to figure out.  Any hints are appreciated.

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Assume there is a simple table "Employees" with the following columns:

```
Code (longint)
FullName (text)
Title (text)
Position (text)
Retired (boolean)
```

[image: table before]

Let us execute the agent script, to remove rows with retired employees.

```
Option Public
Option Declare
UseLSX "*LSXODBC"

Sub Initialize
    Const DSN = "TestODBCConnection"

    Dim con As New ODBCConnection
    Dim qry As New ODBCQuery
    Dim result As New ODBCResultSet
    Dim msg As String

    Call con.ConnectTo(DSN)

    If Not con.IsConnected Then
        MessageBox "Could not connect to " + DSN,,"No connection"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set qry.Connection = con
    Set result.Query = qry

    qry.SQL = "Delete From Employees WHERE Retired = TRUE;"
    result.Execute

    If Not result.Execute Then
          MessageBox result.GetExtendedErrorMessage,, result.GetErrorMessage
     Else
          MsgBox "Ok"
     End If

    result.Close(DB_CLOSE)
    con.Disconnect
End Sub
```

And our table "Employees" now looks like that:

[image: table after]

Comment: Thanks.  I realized that I did do it right but I had a bug in my sql.  Your error capturing code that I added showed me where the error was.  Thanks!